# How do I resize a docked control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pixel

So I have a treeview, that is docked in the left side of a panel. I also have a tabcontrol docked in the right side of a panel. I've worked out most of the visual glitches in my application, but no amount of my internet research/blind testing will work for this glitch..

The problem is, the bottoms of the treeview and the tabcontrol don't match up:

[image]

I can't find any way to make the treeview's height smaller or the tabcontrol's larger. Since it is docked, any time I manually change the size, it just changes back. Is there any way to use some visual style or size assignment to fix this?

Comment: ...or `Margin`...one is external spacing, the other internal.

Comment: Changing the margins doesn't do anything (probably because the controls are docked).

Comment: Did you try what I said? I normally would suggest such a noodle answer but i find fill works much better than the Left and Right. The treeviewer and tabcontrol would both be set to fill their respective panels, hopefuly eliminating the extra space at the bottom when both panels are bound to one master panel.

Comment: Is anyone else seeing this:  the `Padding` property on `TabControl` is of type `Point` and _not_ of type `Padding`?  Could be a bug if I'm seeing it right.

Comment: @JacobGoulden I fixed it! I used 3 more panels to dock the controls, and gave the panel that the treeview was in, a padding-bottom of 1.

Comment: Ok, so according to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.padding.aspx) it's not a bug.  Anyone know why it's a `Point` and not a `Padding` like every other usage I've seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long shot but put each (treeview and tabcontrol) inside seperate panels (Panel1 and Panel2) and set treeview and tabcontol to Fill respectivly. Then put those seperate panels (Panel1 and Panel2) into one panel (Panel3) set Panel1 to left and Panel2 to right in Panel 3.

EDIT:  What DonBoitnott said is probably the best solution (TableLayoutPanel)

Comment: Just an FYI...the TableLayoutPanel is essentially a pre-packaged collection of panels with all the logic built-in to manage proportional arrangement of the controls you add to it.  Check it out.